# Parsing A String - Is There A More Efficient Method than Checking Each Line?

Tags: c#, parsing

I am working on a project to parse out a text file.  The file is output from networking equipment.  The incoming string is anywhere from a few thousand to tens of thousands of lines long.   There will be a variable number of entries with keywords like these:

```
fcN/N is up
   Hardware is Fibre Channel, SFP is short wave laser w/o OFC (SN)
   Port WWN is 20:52:00:0d:ec:ef:b0:40
    Admin port mode is F, trunk mode is on
    snmp link state traps are enabled
    Port vsan is 10

fcipN is up
.....

port-channel-N is trunking
......
```

The N is a number.  There will always be the 'fcN/N' entries, there may or may not be the other two.   The 'fcip' and 'port-channel' entries will have similar status information after each one as the fcN/N entries.   All entries of the same type will be grouped - there won't be an fc followed by an fcip followed by another fc.  Also as a general rule, all the fc entries are listed, then all the port-channel then all the fcip but I don't want to assume that.   At the moment I have about 7 different RegEx patterns I am looking for. I do this by examining each line in turn, however managing all those is cumbersome.  I thought about splitting the string on newline and then some kind of LINQ select to get all of each of the  3 types of entries, but that assumes they are always grouped in the same order.   I also thought about 3 monster regexes to match everything from one entry to the next, but my experience is those are tough to get working and almost unreadable.  Another thing I thought of was first match the three keywords - fc or port-channel or fcip, then have an if statement that matches the patterns unique to those.  That is still matching each line for all 3 patterns though.

To be clear, I have the Regex patterns working. I am looking for a more efficient way to do this than test each line for 6 0r 8 matches.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Do you experience performance issues right now? Are the Regex compiled?

Comment: No. I am just looking for a more elegant way than brute-force.  There may not be a more elegant way and I am cool with that. :)   I didn't know you could compile a Regex, not sure what that means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have two thought:

(1) Your last approach of using if statements to first find the right regex to apply is like to be quite efficient. I'd recommend it.

(2) You can compose regex's like this:

```
var pattern1 = @"abc";
var pattern2 = @"def";
var unionPattern = "((" + pattern1 + ")|(" + pattern2 + "))";
```

This makes it much more readable.

If you never want to find a match that spans lines you should split the file into lines first. That will improve efficiency because the regexes have smaller inputs and will backtrack less.

If your matches span multiple lines but they always start after a new-line, you can you can split the string into chunks first like this:

```
var chunks = Regex.Split(str, "((fc\d)|(fcip\d)|(port-channel-\d)));
```

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear.  The input string already contains lines. That is I declare a StringReader and have it read each line.  I set a string equal to that ReadLine() then search the string for all the matches.

Comment: I think what I am going to do is an approach similar to what I use for the main file. I will search for a keyword. When I find it I will read to the next keyword and process the chunk I just got.  that way I am not checking every single line for each pattern. I start with the 3 main matches, then use others depending on what I find.

Answer (score 0):

You might get clearer and more concise code by using a parser combinator library, such as [Sprache](http://code.google.com/p/sprache/).

Not being a C# programmer, I'm not intimately familiar with this library (and there may well be others for C# as well), but I've used Scala parser combinators to good effect, and they build on and use regular expression parsing.

Whether it make your code more efficient likely depends on how inefficient your code now is.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for raw speed, or efficiency?  If the former, you can split the file into parts and have a thread parsing each part simultaneously.  The trick will be finding a boundary to split on (so that each part contains only whole entries) quickly.  You will also only want to go multithreaded if the total number of lines is large, or the overhead will outweigh the parallelization gains.

Comment: I am looking for efficiency and/or something more elegant than what I have.  There isn't a speed issue.  The entire file averages 30MB.  I search several parts of it and the entire thing is finished in a few seconds.  What I do is search for a command in the file, start reading each line into a string until I hit the next command.  Then I feed that string to a parser that parses that particular part of the file.  This section I am asking about just happens to have a lot of patterns to look for.  I wondered if there was a faster way to do it.